# Can we make a field readable on recordFrom Lightning component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lds

I have created a recordFrom by using

`<lightning:recordForm recordId= "{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Promotion__c" mode="view" columns="1" fields="{!v.FieldSet}" density="compact" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" />`

Since in fieldSet, I have some which are editable, but I don't want to show them in editable form. Like there are Field F1, F2, and F3, I want only F1 open in the editable box but F2 and F3 in non Editable form.

Is there any way it does this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want granular control about which fields are read only and which aren't, you are probably going to need to use `lightning:inputField` components inside a `lightning:recordEditForm`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation